# What good worldbuilding idea podcasts are there?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, worldbuilding-resources

I love exploring interesting ideas of alternative worlds and what-ifs.

Are there any good Podcasts on this subject?

Good Podcasts are defined as ones discussing creative fictional words and situations, that could inspire imagination to create similar ones. In addition they should be interesting, clearly understandable, and either have existing highly recommended episodes or show consistent quality and be ongoing and active.

This question is not looking for Podcasts on techniques and how to build a world. It is looking for information on existing worlds and ideas for new ones.

**Moderator note**: Worldbuilding Resource questions are on topic. The number of different worldbuilding podcasts is low enough that further criteria is not thought to be needed at this time.

Comment: I dunno about podcasts, but [WorldBuilding.SE has its own blog](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/new-blog-post-the-changing-now-previous-when-nature-beats-you-to-the-punch?cb=1).

Comment: A few people from the community, including James the mod, have been recording a world building podcast that's pretty good IMHO, though I may be biased. Check it out: http://monkeylords.com/podcast/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously I've not listened to them all but here are a few that I've found interesting/useful.

- [Worldbuilder's Anvil](https://player.fm/series/worldbuilders-anvil) - This is a discussion podcast where the hosts often wander off an tangents. Their ideas are fairly interesting and they provide quite a few links to resources they've used. They also have over 200 episodes and cover a very broad range of topics.
- [Tabletop terrors - Damage Reduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL29o6IJ5cVpyeTjAfTKCwVXhlaEo1jYQA) is focused on more of a D&D style world but still plenty of interesting topics covered. Again a discussion style between two hosts.
- Shakespeare and Dragons - I can't actually find this as of yet but I remember thoroughly enjoying it and, if I can find you the link, I'll get back to you with more detail.